# Null value error caused by linking StatefulWidget inside Row

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I want to make an App in Flutter. I created a Stateless Widget and a StatefulWidget and tried to link the StatefulWidget in a Row in the StatelessWidget. But for some reason, I get a null check error, when I put a StatefulWidget inside a Row in a StatelessWidget.

Here is my code so far:

````
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add_rounded,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconSize: 45.0,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconSize: 35.0,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            Courses(),
          ],
        )
        ),
      );
  }
}

class Courses extends StatefulWidget {
  const Courses({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CoursesState createState() => _CoursesState();
}

class _CoursesState extends State<Courses> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Content',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

```
````

When running this code, I get this error message: "Null check operator used on a null value"

Comment: is the error not occuring when you don't use the Stateful widget _CoursesState inside the row Widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `Courses()` inside a `Flexible` widget solves the error.

```
    Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(child: Courses()),
          ],
        ),
```